# Perform mouse-scroll screen on tmux

Tags: configuration, tmux, xterm

After extremely painful struggle to manage to mouse-scroll in tmux, finally decide to use back the `xterm` together with

```
set mouse off
```

this's what found (in a forgot site)

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

it does scroll... in very bad defected way i.e. just ~57 lines

How to fix this, to have it work just at non-tmux normal terminal